# Expose an object from an Angular service using Getter function return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is the code:

authServ.getUser() returns {} (an empty object, which corresponds to the declaration of this var), from everywhere, even after the revision that I have made to the return syntax according to this [question][1].

Can anyone please advise what is the issue?, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work

```
app.factory('authService', function($http){
    var authServ = {};
    var currentUser = {};
        authServ.authUser = function(){
            return $http.head('/users/me', {withCredentials: true});
        },
        authServ.getUser =  function(){
            return currentUser;
        },
        authServ.setCompany =  function(companyId){
            currentUser.company = companyId;
        }
        authServ.loadCurrentUser = function(){
            $http.get('/users/me', {withCredentials: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
                currentUser.company = currentUser.company ? currentUser.company : data.main_company;
                currentUser.companies = [];
                for(var i in data.roles){
                    currentUser.companies.push(data.roles[i]['company_name']);
                    if(data.roles[i]['company'] == currentUser.company)
                        currentUser.role = data.roles[i]['role_type'];
                }
                console.log(currentUser);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                currentUser.role = 'guest';
                currentUser.company = 1;
            });
        }

        return authServ;
});
```

WORKING CODE:

```
run(function($rootScope, $location, $http, authService){
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, rejection){
    if(rejection.status == 401)
        $location.path('/login');
})
authService.loadCurrentUser().then(function(){
    console.log(authService.getUser());
});


});
app.factory('authService', function ($http) {
    authServ = {};
    that = this;
    that.currentUser = {};
    authServ.authUser = function () {
        return $http.head('/users/me', {
            withCredentials: true
        });
    },
    authServ.getUser = function () {
        return that.currentUser;
    },
    authServ.setCompany = function (companyId) {
        that.currentUser.company = companyId;
    },
    authServ.loadCurrentUser = function () {
        return $http.get('/users/me', {
            withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            that.currentUser.company = that.currentUser.company ? that.currentUser.company : data.main_company;
            that.currentUser.companies = [];
            for (var i in data.roles) {
                that.currentUser.companies.push(data.roles[i]['company_name']);
                if (data.roles[i]['company'] == that.currentUser.company) that.currentUser.role = data.roles[i]['role_type'];
            }
            console.log(that.currentUser);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            that.currentUser.role = 'guest';
            that.currentUser.company = 1;
        });
    }
    return authServ;
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/V9Ex6/1/

Comment: change `return that;` to 'return authServ;'

Comment: Apparently, I completely forgot about the fact that I am loading this data asynchronously, and that in order to access this data from out side I should return the promise object from the loadUser function, and then use the .then() function to assign a callback to it's resolve.

edited the code, and the fiddle, thank you for helping me sza

Comment: @sza say I would like to render the companies in a select menu,  how can I do that considering that I get this data from an XHR request?

BTW, thank you very much for all of your help so far

Comment: I found a demo online, hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/2JWb2/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure issue. Try

```
app.factory('authService', function($http){
    var authServ = {};
    that = this; //that captures the current closure
    this.currentUser = {};
    authServ.getUser =  function(){
        return that.currentUser;
    },
```

And change `loadCurrentUser` to access to the variable using `that.currentUser`.

**Edit**:

```
authService.loadCurrentUser();
console.log(authService.getUser());
```

The user is not guaranteed to be printed out since `loadCurrentUser` loads the user asynchronously. You should change `loadCurrentUser` to take a callback function in order to get the user value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What should I return then?, this, that, or authServ?

Comment: Use `that`, make it consistent.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loadCurrentUser' 

when trying to call loadCurrentUser() from the run function of the app, I have posted the updated code, thank you for your time

Comment: How did you call it? like authService.loadCurrentUser() ?

Comment: authServ.loadCurrentUser = function(){...}

Should have I used that in this context?, I am a bit confused

Comment: Nope, you need to call under the factory name 'authService', make sure you inject the factory in your controller

Comment: I have posted my full code, including the app.run() function, thank you again

Comment: I mean, returning authServ doesn't throw an type error, but still I get an empty object logged out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, mind you I haven't tested it :)

```
app.factory('authService', function($http){
    return {
        authUser: function(){
            return $http.head('/users/me', {withCredentials: true});
        },
        getUser:  function(){
            return currentUser;
        },
        setCompany:  function(companyId){
            currentUser.company = companyId;
        },
        loadCurrentUser: function(){
            $http.get('/users/me', {withCredentials: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
                currentUser.company = currentUser.company ? currentUser.company : data.main_company;
                currentUser.companies = [];
                for(var i in data.roles){
                    currentUser.companies.push(data.roles[i]['company_name']);
                    if(data.roles[i]['company'] == currentUser.company)
                        currentUser.role = data.roles[i]['role_type'];
                }
                console.log(currentUser);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                currentUser.role = 'guest';
                currentUser.company = 1;
            });
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: currentUser is not defined', after adding a declaration for this var, I got the same problem as with my code.

Thank you for taking the time to post your answer!