# How to resolve an XHR request prior to loading a partial with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Short version:

This plunkr page gets role as undefined, and therefore won't display the content that should be displayed, but when triggered by a click, the role appears to be correct.

sample plunkr to emphasize the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QHUpCv?p=preview

Whole version:

I have a static menu that is persistent for all of the views in my application.
For obvious reasons I would like to resolve an XHR request before displaying it.

Tried using an-init, but it just makes the function call asynchronously, tried using promises from the $q object, but that didn't help either.

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<div ng-init="loadCurrentUser()" ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

controller:

```
controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location, authService){
    $scope.loadCurrentUser = authService.loadCurrentUser;
    $scope.model = {message : 'Hello Oleg'};
    $scope.logCurrentUser = function(){
        var user = authService.getUser();
        console.log(user);
    }

});
```

service:

```
 authServ.loadCurrentUser = function () {
        alert('here');
        // var defer = $q.defer();
        return $http.get('/users/me', {
            withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            that.currentUser.company = {};
            that.currentUser.company.id = that.currentUser.company.id ? that.currentUser.company.id : data.main_company;            
            that.currentUser.companies = [];
            for (var i in data.roles) {
                that.currentUser.companies[data.roles[i]['company']] = data.roles[i]['company_name'];
                if (data.roles[i]['company'] == that.currentUser.company.id){
                    that.currentUser.role = data.roles[i]['role_type']; 
                    that.currentUser.company.name = data.roles[i]['company_name'];
                    // console.log(that.currentUser.role);
                } 
            }
            // defer.resolve(data);
            // defer.resolve();
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            that.currentUser.role = 'guest';
            that.currentUser.company = 1;
            defer.reject("reject");
        });  
    // return defer.promise;
    }
```

Restrict role-access-level directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('restrict', function(authService){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: {
            // : '@'
        },
        link: function(){
            // alert('ergo sum!');
        },
        compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
            var user = authService.getUser();
                if(user.role != attr.access){
                console.log(attr.access);
                console.log(user.role);//Always returns undefined!
                    element.children().remove();
                    element.remove();           
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are doing with `authService.getUser()`

You can watch for a variable in your template, which you can set in the `success` of the `XHR` call.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<div ng-show="userLoaded" ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

In the controller, in the success call back, you can do:

```
this.userLoaded = true;
```

Note that you will need to `bind` the success call back function to the `$scope` (as `this`/ context). You can use:

```
.success(angular.bind(this, function (data, status, headers, config) {...},
    data, status, headers, config));
```

Also I am not sure what you mean by 'that'. If you want to access the `$scope` inside the callback, use `angular.bind` as above.

**EDIT**
You can use `ng-if` if using angular 1.1.x. Also if you don't want the elements to be just hidden and not to create them at all, use `ng-switch`. Note that `ng-switch` creates a new `$scope`. Please see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/lJSp-hkileY

In your directive function, you are checking `user.role` in the compile function which gets evaluated before you actually try to authenticate user.

Comment: Should I use ng-show or ng-if?.
I was using that because I had a problem with the geeter method of this service, as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104056/expose-an-object-from-an-angular-service-using-getter-function-return-undefined

Comment: Doesn't work, I still get undefined logged out.
Perhaps I forgot to mention that I am using a directive, that tries to remove elements that are not supposed to be displayed to the current user role in it's $compile function, I've added the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

A bit monkey patched solution, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/K23B4/4/

Brief explanation:
Passing the function that is in charge for making the neeeded DOM modifications as a parameter to the service, saving it in a private member, and then calling this function as part of the AJAX callback.

Not perfect, but definitely better then having your ajax at the controllers or directives.

application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory("auth", function(){
    var onUserHandler;

    return {
        onUser: function(handler){
             onUserHandler = handler;    
        },

        getAuth: function(){
             setTimeout(onUserHandler, 3000);
        }
    }
});

function Main($scope, auth){
    $scope.src = "empty.html";

    auth.onUser(function(){
        $scope.src = "menu.html";
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    auth.getAuth();
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="empty.html">
    <div>wait for it...</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">
    <div>Hello user!!!</div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-include src="src"></div>
</div>
```

This code was contributed by user @Peled Roy
https://stackoverflow.com/users/357506/peled-roy